# asp net core маршрутизация с перегруженным методом GET POST выдает error Document Expired

Tags: asp.net-core, маршрутизация

У меня есть контроллер с методами

```
 [Route("Index)]
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult Index()
 {

 }


 [Route("Index")]
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Index (string Profession, string City, int Course, string Specialization,  int page = 1) //(UserModel model)  
 {

 }
```

пытаюсь реализовать поисковик, но маршрут остается статичным (Search/Index) и когда я перехожу назад выдает ошибку Document Expired. После нажатии кнопки поиск тоже остается статичным

Не могу настроит маршрут пытался через map.routes сделать не помогло. через атрибуты тоже